# remove parameter of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters, splice

I ran into a little trouble within my javascript. Basically I am trying to remove a parameter in an array after the startEventDate has passed the endEventDate. The issue is I am only splicing from the index of the array. How can I remove specific parameters of the array?

Here is my code.

```
    <div style="position:absolute; top:145px; left:0px; z-index:9999; width:350px; background-image:url(); height:125px; width:396px; padding:5px; font-size:12px;">

      <p id="af1" style="display:none;"><strong style="color:#003399">Holiday Schedule</strong><br>
          December 24 &#8211; 5:00 a.m. &#8211; 3:00 pm &#8211; December 25 <span style="color:#F00">CLOSED</span>; <BR>
      December 31 &#8211; 5:00 a.m. &#8211; 3:00 pm &#8211; January 1, 2015 8:00 a.m. &#8211; 10 p.m.</p><!---->
     <p id="af2" style="display:none;"><strong style="color:#003399"> Pool Holiday Schedule</strong><br />
Lap pool will close Monday, December 29 at 730 a.m., and will be closed through Tuesday, December 30, due to pool maintenance. The pool will reopen for Holiday hours beginning Wednesday, December 31 at 5:00 a.m.. Regular hours will resume Friday, January2 at 5:00 a.m.</p> 

  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

 var af = new Crossfader( new Array('af1','af2'), 500, 5000 ); //Crossfader references an earlier Javascript written to rotate between an element with the id listed as it’s parameter.

 var today = new Date(); //The javascript below is written in order to display the id’s ‘af1’ and ‘af2’ as block between the current date and end event date. After the end date the display is set back to none.

 var startEventDate = new Date(); // time is optional
 var endEventDate = new Date ("January 1, 2015 12:00:00");
 if ((today >= startEventDate)  && (today <=endEventDate)) {
     document.getElementById("af1").style.display = "block"
 }
 else{
        Crossfader.splice(index, af1); //This splices the index parameter ‘af1’ out of the array after the startEventDate is greater than the endEventDate.
 }
 var endEventDate = new Date ("January 1, 2015 12:00:00");
 if ((today >= startEventDate)  && (today <=endEventDate)) {
     document.getElementById("af2").style.display = "block"
 }
 else{
     Crossfader.splice(index, af2); //How do I splice or remove individual parameters of Crossfader array after the startEventDate has been passed?
 }

</script>
```

and here is the code to the Crossfade

```
    <script>

    var useBSNns;

    if (useBSNns) {
         if (typeof(bsn) == "undefined")
              bsn = {}
           var _bsn = bsn;
    } else {
          var _bsn = this;
    }

    _bsn.Crossfader = function (divs, fadetime, delay ) {   
         this.nAct = -1;
         this.aDivs = divs;

         for (var i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
           document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.opacity = 0;
        document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.position = "absolute";
           document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)";
          document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.visibility = "hidden";
         }

         this.nDur = fadetime;
      this.nDelay = delay;
      this._newfade();
    }

    _bsn.Crossfader.prototype._newfade = function() {
      if (this.nID1)
        clearInterval(this.nID1);
           this.nOldAct = this.nAct;
        this.nAct++;

        if (!this.aDivs[this.nAct]) this.nAct = 0;

        if (this.nAct == this.nOldAct)
        return false;

      document.getElementById( this.aDivs[this.nAct] ).style.visibility = "visible";
      this.nInt = 50;
      this.nTime = 0;
      var p=this;
      this.nID2 = setInterval(function() { p._fade() }, this.nInt);
    }

    _bsn.Crossfader.prototype._fade = function() {
      this.nTime += this.nInt;
        var ieop = Math.round( this._easeInOut(this.nTime, 0, 1, this.nDur) * 100 );
        var op = ieop / 100;
        document.getElementById( this.aDivs[this.nAct] ).style.opacity = op;
        document.getElementById( this.aDivs[this.nAct] ).style.filter = "alpha(opacity="+ieop+")";

      if (this.nOldAct > -1) {
        document.getElementById( this.aDivs[this.nOldAct] ).style.opacity = 1 - op;
            document.getElementById( this.aDivs[this.nOldAct] ).style.filter = "alpha(opacity="+(100 - ieop)+")";
         }

         if (this.nTime == this.nDur) {
              clearInterval( this.nID2 );

      if (this.nOldAct > -1)
           document.getElementById( this.aDivs[this.nOldAct] ).style.visibility = "hidden"; 
        var p=this;
        this.nID1 = setInterval(function() { p._newfade() }, this.nDelay);
      }
    }

    _bsn.Crossfader.prototype._easeInOut = function(t,b,c,d) {
      return c/2 * (1 - Math.cos(Math.PI*t/d)) + b;
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Where is the Crossfader code?  What values to the variables `index` and `af11 and `af2` have?

Comment: added the Crossfader code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `splice()` incorrectly. Check out the [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

You want to do this:

```
Crossfader.splice(index, 1, "af2");
```

to remove that specific item from the array.